# How do I use a shell script to add content to a specific location in the text?

Tags: shell

On an ubuntu 18.04 system, I look at the contents of this file
cat /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml
The last part reads as follows：

```
    <key name='notify-on-connect' type='b'>
      <summary>Notify on connect</summary>
      <description>
        If true, show a notification when a user connects to the system.
      </description>
      <default>true</default>
    </key>
  </schema>
</schemalist>
```

Now I want to insert a paragraph at the beginning of the penultimate line, which when inserted will look like this:

```
    <key name='notify-on-connect' type='b'>
      <summary>Notify on connect</summary>
      <description>
        If true, show a notification when a user connects to the system.
      </description>
      <default>true</default>
    </key>

    <key name=’enabled’ type=’b’>
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
        If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
        protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
        desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>

  </schema>
</schemalist>
```

The second paragraph above is what I have inserted, how should I write the shell script to achieve this insertion? Insert a piece of content at the specified location, and for this piece of content, the space before each line is also fixed
For example, the first line of the second paragraph above, , is preceded by 4 spaces. The second line, Enable remote access to the desktop, is preceded by 6 spaces. How should I script to achieve this effect.

Comment: Toiedit XML files, use XML tools. ex. xmlstarlet, xmllint

Comment: Why did you replace all the double quotes with invalid single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

The best option when working with XML is to use an XML-aware tool, which will end up being far more robust than depending on specific formatting like indentation, or line numbers. For example, using XSLT and `xsltproc` to insert a new `key` node into the last schema of a document:

```sh
xsltproc - /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml <<'EOF'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="schema[last()]">
    <schema>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
      <key name="enabled" type="b">
        <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
        <description>
          If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
          protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
          desktop using a VNC viewer.
        </description>
        <default>false</default>
      </key>
    </schema>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
```

The output can be redirected to a temporary file and then copied over the original, or you can use it with something like the handy [`sponge`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html) program from the `moreutils` package.

The stylesheet can also be saved to its own file instead of putting it in an inline heredoc; in that case replace the `-` argument (Which tells `xsltproc` to read from standard input) with the name of the file.

Comment: The stylesheet can also be saved to its own file instead of putting it in an inline heredoc; in that case replace the - argument (Which tells xsltproc to read from standard input) with the name of the file.  @Shawn，Can you give an example of  “replace the - argument (Which tells xsltproc to read from standard input) with the name of the file”

Comment: Uh... `xsltproc thestylesheet.xml theschema.xml`

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn，When I use your method:

[image]

Then I tail the file:

[image]

This paragraph:

```
    <key name=’enabled’ type=’b’>
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
        If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
        protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
        desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>
```

It was not inserted into the /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml .

I want to inserted this paragraph into  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml。

What parameter of this command do I need to change：

xsltproc - /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml